Quarkus MongoDB returns date 1970 if Java type is OffsetDateTime
MongoDB validation schema:
bsonType: "object",
required: ["createdAt"],
properties: {
    createdAt: {
        bsonType: "date"
    }
}

Java class:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MongoEntity(collection = "dogs")
public class Dog {
  private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
}

Java object creation:
var dog = new Dog();
dog.setCreatedAt(OffsetDateTime.now());

Insert document:
mongoDatabase.getCollection("dogs", Dog.class).insertOne(dog);

Retrieve document:
var dog = col.find().into(new ArrayList<>()).get(0);
System.out.println(dog.getCreatedAt()); //1970-01-20T21:13:08.290+01:00
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now()); //2024-04-29T12:58:10.168902949+02:00

In database the 1970 date is set.
Does MongoDB support OffsetDateTime? Is something missing to insert the date in correct format?

Somewhere underway seconds and milliseconds since the epoch have been confused. 1970-01-20T21:13:08.290+01:00 is 1714388290 milliseconds after the epoch. 1714388290 seconds after the epoch is Monday 29 April 2024 12:58:10 GMT+02:00.

Yeah, there was already a codec but seconds and milliseconds were confused.

The MongoDB Java driver didn't support OffsetDate and OffsetDateTime.
You need to create a Codec and a CodecProvider to support them, Quarkus will automatically detect them add the to the client: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#simplifying-mongodb-client-usage-using-bson-codec
